# Display values with NAs in xaxis of plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly

How can I display in `plotly` bar chart a `x` value with `NAs` in `y` column?

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, NA),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

fig
```

Comment: Would `y = replace_na(c(20, 14, NA), 0)` work for you

Comment: I thought about it but I would like to see if there is another way

Comment: What do you expect for an NA bar

Comment: You can post the answer if something does not come out

Comment: I am just trying to understand how you will visualize a missing value.  It may be better to have another category which counts the number of missing values

Comment: maybe with a hovet text or annotation that would clarify that they are NAs and not really 0 in combination with your solution?

Comment: Where do you want NA to show up in a numerical axis, taller than other bars, or with no bar at all with empty space

Comment: the second opion